# How to fix a bug in the catch function Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a code to ban, and I encountered such a problem that the bot does not stop playing the code

code

```
message.guild.members.ban(args[0]).catch(err => {
            if (err.code === 10013) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Oh no!').setDescription('No user').setColor('ff3333')]})
            if (err.code === 50035) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Oh no!').setDescription('No user').setColor('ff3333')]})
        })
         message.reply({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Ban').setDescription(`User - <@${args[0]}> ban\nMod - ${message.author}\nReson - ${args.slice(1).join(' ')}`)] })
```

( Decided )

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Um... okey, okey

Comment: Then `err.code` does not equal 10013 or 50035. Log the value and see what you're getting. Try using `==`, the value may be a string

Comment: Thanks for answering. Tried it, didn't help, same bug

Comment: Can paste what log you see

Comment: You can also use [`Constants.APIError`](https://discord.js.org/#%2Fdocs%2Fmain%2Fstable%2Ftypedef%2FConstants=) instead of using `10013` etc. For example: `import {Constants} from 'discord.js'` or `const {Constants} = require('discord.js')`, `if (err.code === Constants.APIError.UNKNOWN_USER) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````js
message.guild.members.ban(args[0]).then(banu => {
message.reply({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Ban').setDescription(`User - ${banu} ban\Mod - ${message.author}\nReson - ${args.slice(1).join(' ')}`)] })
}).catch(err => {
            if (err.code === 10013) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Oh no!').setDescription('No user').setColor('ff3333')]})
            if (err.code === 50035) return message.channel.send({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Oh no!').setDescription('No user').setColor('ff3333')]})
        })```
````